# Appending every line of text file if equation is satisfied

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I have a text file, File.txt. Suppose it contains thousands of lines of the following form:

```
A, B, word, C, D
```

The "word" part does not change from one line to the next, however every other string (here "A", "B", "C", "D") is in fact a float value and does change from one line to the next. Let's say I have some variable that I define as Q (some float value). I want to append each line with either a S or a F. I'd like to do append the line with a S if ((D-4)/3)-A=Q±1, or with a F if this is not the case. For example, let's consider the following (small-scale) example:

```
1, 0, text, 1, 16
2, 3, text, 3, 18.5
3, 5, text, 1, 3
4, 4, text, 55, 25
```

If Q=3, then the script would append the lines in the following way:

```
1, 0, text, 1, 16, S
2, 3, text, 3, 18.5, S
3, 5, text, 1, 3, F
4, 4, text, 55, 25, S
```

So to generalize my question, how do I append every line of a text file with a string that depends on whether a certain condition is met within that line?

Comment: would it be okay if the result is written into another file?

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: However, if you do not know how to use files: read with ``with open(theFileName, "r") as f:`` and in that block f.readlines() reads the lines, when changing "r" to "w" you can simply write to the file with f.write(theText)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write it into another file (it has to be a different file otherwise this approach won't work):

```
with open(sourcefile, mode='r') as source:
    with open(targetfile, mode='w') as target:
        for line in source:
            A, B, word, C, D = line.split(', ')
            A, B, C, D = float(A), float(B), float(C), float(D)
            if -1 <= Q - (((D-4)/3)-A) <= 1:
                newline = line + ', S\n'
            else:
                newline = line + ', F\n'
            target.write(newline)
```

This just checks if the difference is smaller than 1, if you actually wanted to check if it's Q+1 or Q-1 then you could use this:

```
cond = (Q+1, Q-1)
with open(sourcefile, mode='r') as source:
    with open(targetfile, mode='w') as target:
        for line in source:
            A, B, word, C, D = line.split(', ')
            A, B, C, D = float(A), float(B), float(C), float(D)
            if ((D-4)/3)-A in cond:
                newline = line + ', S\n'
            else:
                newline = line + ', F\n'
            target.write(newline)
```

Comment: I seem to only be getting "F" for every line when in fact many of the lines should have "S" - does this have to do with the "cond" part or is this some mistake on my end?

Comment: @RealFL I think I may have forgot one parenthesis in my condition. I updated the answer :) Let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry to keep pestering you with this, but I'm still getting the same problem - I can confirm that it has nothing to do with the equation in the line because even if I make the range enormous, i.e. cond = (Q+1000, Q-1000) and write "if A in cond" later, I still only get F for every line.

Comment: Did you try the first approach? The second was just in case I misunderstood the question.

Comment: Oh... well actually yes, the first approach works just fine! Sorry about that, I misunderstood what you wrote and assumed only the second case worked for what I was doing. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score -1):

You could go through every line like this:

```
for l in f.readlines():
    l = l.strip('\r\n')
    if l: # maybe the last line is empty
        A, B, _, C, D = l.split() # extract the values
        A, B, C, D = float(A), float(B), float(C), float(D) # convert from str to float
        newL = l + ", " + "SF"[abs((((D-4)/3)-A) - Q) <= 1]

        print(newL) # however you could pipe the output into the new file
```